# Show function in laravel return blank array[]

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a Models called Prediction and Memeberdetails in my code. I want to show the details of particular employee on next page mean when user clicks on Employee Number it should redirect to new page and all the details of that member should be displayed.
When I am returning model Membersdetails it's working absolutely fine, similarly want to do it for model Prediction, but when I am trying to return for this, it return blank array not sure what I am doing wrong in this.

Here is my route

```
Route::resource('/detail', PredictionController::class);
```

This is my view from where I want user to redirect and get details of Employee

```
columns: [
                {
                    data: 'EmployeeNumber',
                        name: 'EmployeeNumber',
                    render:function(data, type, row){
                    //console.log(row)}
                    //return "a"}
                    return "<a href='/detail/"+ row.id +"'>" + row.EmployeeNumber+"</a>"}
                },
```

And this is my Controller:

```
public function show(Prediction $prediction)
    
        {
            
            $Attrition_correlator = Attrition_correlators::all();
            //return view('admin.members.Detailspage',compact('prediction','Attrition_correlator'));
            return $prediction;
        }
```

And this is my model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Prediction extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['Feedback'];
}
```

What I am doing wrong in this or what I am missing same code works fine for other Model but returning blank with this model...any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing  `$prediction` to `$detail`

```
public function show(Prediction $detail)
{
            
   return $detail;
}
```

It should match route params.Run following command and see routes generated from resources

```
php artisan route:list
```